# How to get keys of a generic type that extends a known interface?

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, properties, typescript-generics

I am a bit of a TS noob, so forgive me if this is dumb.

I have an interface that takes a type that extends a known interface (let's call the known type A and the other type B). I am trying to get a known, required, readonly key that links to a readonly array. The interface works for A but not B.

```js
export type KeysOfReadonlyArraysOf<Obj> = {
    [K in keyof Obj]:
        Obj[K] extends ReadonlyArray<any> ?
            K :
            never
}[keyof Obj]

export type ReadonlyArrayValuesOf<T, V extends KeysOfReadonlyArraysOf<T>> =
    T[V] extends Readonly<any[]> ? T[V][number] : never;

interface foo {
    bar: ReadonlyArray<string>,
    baz: number
    
}


interface itest2<T extends foo>{
    field:ReadonlyArrayValuesOf<T,"bar">
}
```

"bar" ends up red with no intelisense.

If it helps, my tsconfig is this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    
  },
  "include": ["src","__tests__"]
}
```

Comment: See [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992) for a discussion of why this sort of thing doesn't work for generics.  But I don't understand why you'd bother trying to get that working instead of just doing the direct indexed access as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Wzaokm).  Could you [edit] to clarify?